# Discord bot doubles and triples logs when calling it for the second and third time

Tags: python, logging, discord

I'm trying to make a simple discord bot that does only one thing - prints a list of strings to the chat at the initialization. It's for a bigger project, the discord side is for notifications only.

The following code I've written does exactly what I want:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


def run_discord_bot(list_to_print):
    client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.all())

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print("working!")
        channel = client.get_channel(MY CHANNEL ID)
        for item in list_to_print:
            await channel.send(item)
        await client.close()

    client.run("MY TOKEN")


run_discord_bot(["msg1", "msg2"])
run_discord_bot(["msg3", "msg4"])
run_discord_bot(["msg5", "msg6"])
```

messages the bot sent to the channel

[image]

But, there is a small issue with it. It doubles and triples the logs. This is the console output after running this simple program (the IDs are different, but I've changed the names for better readability):

```
[2023-06-14 00:50:00] [INFO    ] discord.client: logging in using static token
[2023-06-14 00:50:01] [INFO    ] discord.gateway: Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: id1).
working!
[2023-06-14 00:50:04] [INFO    ] discord.client: logging in using static token
[2023-06-14 00:50:04] [INFO    ] discord.client: logging in using static token
[2023-06-14 00:50:05] [INFO    ] discord.gateway: Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: id2).
[2023-06-14 00:50:05] [INFO    ] discord.gateway: Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: id2).
working!
[2023-06-14 00:50:07] [INFO    ] discord.client: logging in using static token
[2023-06-14 00:50:07] [INFO    ] discord.client: logging in using static token
[2023-06-14 00:50:07] [INFO    ] discord.client: logging in using static token
[2023-06-14 00:50:08] [INFO    ] discord.gateway: Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: id3).
[2023-06-14 00:50:08] [INFO    ] discord.gateway: Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: id3).
[2023-06-14 00:50:08] [INFO    ] discord.gateway: Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: id3).
working!

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Why is that? How can I prevent it from logging the same thing multiple times?

I've tried to use `log_handler=None` while calling `client.run()`, but it removes logging entirely (no surprise there).

Comment: You are creating three different bots, not one bot. That's why you get triple the logs (and triple the connections, etc.).

Comment: @AKX yup, but as you can see, the message "working!" is printed 3 times, the messages on the discord server are alright; only when calling the function again i get multiple logs, but the session IDs are the same on one call

Comment: Yes, the bot has one identity, as it were, on the server, but it's still making 3 connections.

Comment: But anyway, why do you need 3 separate calls to `run_discord_bot`? What's your actual end goal here?

Comment: @AKX My end goal is very simple. I want the bot to send the messages when i need it (when i need it = when my main program finds something interesting and wants to notify me and other users on the server), and then shut down itself (because the main program will be periodically restarting itself, i cant have other scripts running). The calls i've used in the code are only to show the problem - in my main program i might call it once, a dozen of times or never - depending on the main program's finds

Comment: Well, then you have two options: deal with each call to the bot printing out log messages (because it is doing all of those things it's logging about on every call), or restructure things so the bot only connects once and you can call a function to have it say things.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm still not quite clear on what you want to do in the end, here's an example that only creates one client, does three things, then disconnects. (The `make_msg_func` function creating and returning inner async function is a bit on the side of advanced magic, but it's pretty generic.)

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all())

on_ready_funcs = []


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for fun in on_ready_funcs:
        await fun()
    await client.close()


def make_msg_func(list_to_print):
    async def func():
        channel = client.get_channel(MY_CHANNEL_ID)
        for item in list_to_print:
            await channel.send(item)

    return func


on_ready_funcs.append(make_msg_func(["msg1", "msg2"]))
on_ready_funcs.append(make_msg_func(["msg3", "msg4"]))
on_ready_funcs.append(make_msg_func(["msg5", "msg6"]))
client.run("MY TOKEN")
```

Comment: I should have stated it in the post, it's my fault. I have a structure of 2 python scripts: `main.py` and `discord_bot.py`. I want the discord bot to send some messages when the `main.py` script calls for it. That's why I placed the whole bot in a function `run_discord_bot()`. The function calls that I've put in the code might be a little misleading, they won't be there. Only the `main.py` script will call the bot. Then, after that call, the bot should shut down itself - it's also important.